# Using Mapbox places, can I get all the "child" places of a certain place as well?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am building a location based market places, and using mapbox places for all my location related data.

I am currently building the filter of the marketplace and facing a little "problem"

Assume I have 5 products in these locations, defined by the user:

1. product A - Location: Barcelona, Sapin
2. product B - Location: Madrid, Spain
3. product C - Location: Spain, Europe
4. product D - Location: Gothic Quarter, Barcelona, Spain.
5. product E - Location: Europe

For my products, it makes perfect sense to give a product a location as specific as product d, or as broad as product e.

My problem is that when filtering products by location and for example setting it to "Europe" - only product e would appear, where I would like them all to appear.
If filtering to "Spain", I would like products A, B, C & D to appear.
If filtering by "Barcelona" I would like product A & D to appear.

You get the hang of it.

How can I get this done? How can I tell the system something like

```
if(product.location == filteringLocation || product.location.isChildOf(filteringLocation)){
showProduct()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add *"Europe"* your A, B, C, D products. 
Then you can query them by simply matching the information that is given for each location.
This guarantees that every product you add has the same signature, but the entire location is optional.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand what you mean. Add to Europe all the locations? Add it how to where? Also let's say I so this manually for a for the locations in my example, there are literally billions of other "heritage" situations.

Comment: @Tsabary What I mean is that you should make the location fields that you *really* need required, so that you can filter your products by all or part of them. So for example every product must have in his location a *street name, district, city, country*  so that you can filter them by e.g. *district* but still all the products of that city will be considered also.

Comment: More related to Mapbox, if you don't want to change your logic behind this, you should probably try to use geocoding to get all the information about a product you need. Here's a [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/) on the topic.